# Retrofit 2.0 access to constructed request URL

Tags: android, retrofit

When there is a failure parsing the JSON from a response, it would be beneficial to be able to log the specific API request who's response had issues. To, do so, I would like to add a `CallAdapterFactory` that maintained the URL of the request and attached it to the error message in the `Callback#onFailure`.

I looked into the `OkHttpCall` code, and afaik the constructed URL in `createRawCall()` is never exposed beyond `OkHttpCall`. Is there a way to access the URL string constructed by Retrofit in order to log the request?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an [`Interceptor`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Interceptor.html).

```
private static class UrlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String url = request.urlString();

        Log.d(TAG, url);

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

You can add this to your client like so:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new UrlInterceptor());
```

If you want to log more details, you could take a look at [`HttpLoggingInterceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor).

Comment: That doesn't work for my purposes, the URL string has to be know after this point. My goal is to be able to attach it to the error message I report when there was an issue converting the response. It needs to be at the Retrofit abstraction level, not the OkHttp abstraction level.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution for Okhttp3 :

```
static class URLInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
       Request request = chain.request();
        String url = request.url().toString();

        Log.d("TAG", url);
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```